# Batch script to get website ip address?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ip-address

I'm trying to put together a batch file, that will ping a website, and assign its ip to a variable - I've searched around, but haven't really been able to put something together. Can anyone shove me in the right direction.

Tim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the ping command.
The idea is to get the part between the [], of the ping output.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set myServer=google.de

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=[]" %%a IN ('ping -n 1 !myServer!') DO (
 if "%%b" NEQ "" set ip=%%b
)
echo ip is %ip%
```

Comment: Better use `ping -n 1 -w 0 !myServer!` to have no wait.

Comment: The -w 0 seems only to take an effect, if -n is higher than 1

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is look up the addresses, you might want to use `nslookup` rather than `ping`. Doing a search for "nslookup batch" gives you a bunch of results, including [this](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5208-6230-0.html?forumID=101&threadID=239422&messageID=2330630) one that looks like it should be fairly easy to adapt since it stores the result in variables.

Answer (score 1):

Same as @jeb answer, above, but without using `EnableDelayedExpansion`, just replace "www.google.com" with you favorite site or `%variablename%`:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %f in ('ping -4 -n 1 www.google.com ^|find /i "pinging"') do echo IP=%f
```