# Batch file to print URL and IP list for hosts file

Tags: batch-file

I have a list of host/url in a txt file (let's say URLList.txt) and I need to get the IP list of all of them.
There are a lot of url, so it will be pretty long to do that manually.
Basically I was wondering if, based on the input file list, I could get a result like this:

```
host1 IP1
host2 IP2
.
.
hostn IPn
```

For example

```
s12web 120.234.567.12
s34web 12.444.32.22
```

etc

Then I would put this output and copy it to my hosts file

Thanks a lot for your great help,

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to do that, credit to @Lizz for [the way to find the ip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13217608/5022761):

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%h in ("URLList.txt") do (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%f in ('ping -4 -n 1 %%h ^|find /i "pinging"') do if not "%%f"=="" (
        echo.%%h %%f
    )
)
pause
```

And to echo it to a file you could use this:

```
@echo off
type nul>IPList.txt
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%h in ("URLList.txt") do (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%f in ('ping -4 -n 1 %%h ^|find /i "pinging"') do if not "%%f"=="" (
        echo.%%h %%f
    )>>IPList.txt
)
pause
```

As @aschipfl pointed out, another solution that's more elegant:

```
@echo off
>IPList.txt (
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%h in ("URLList.txt") do (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%f in ('ping -4 -n 1 %%h ^|find /i "pinging"') do if not "%%f"=="" (
        echo.%%h %%f
    )
)
)
```

Comment: There is no need to initialise an empty file if you put the entire `for` loop in between parentheses and redirect its output once by `>`...